# Python - Export AWS Cognito User Pool - NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to retrieve user list from my AWS Cognito User Pool.

When I enter this command to PowerShell, I can get `users.json` file as a result;

`aws --region eu-central-XXXX cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id eu-central-XXXX_AAAAAAA --output json > ~/users.json`

I wrote a Python code to do same;

```
import boto3

REGION = 'eu-central-XXXX'
USER_POOL_ID = 'eu-central-XXXX_AAAAAAA'

client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', REGION)

user_records = client.list_users(UserPoolId=USER_POOL_ID)
print(user_records)
```

But I got `botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials`.

I see that I have `~/.aws/config` and `~/.aws/credentials` files and they have my information, I checked.

What is the problem? How can I solve my problem?

Comment: did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35802492/467944

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution;

```
import boto3

REGION = 'eu-central-XXXX'
USER_POOL_ID = 'eu-central-XXXX_AAAAAAA'

session = boto3.Session(profile_name = "YOUR_PROFILE_NAME_ON_CREDENTIALS_FILE"
client = session.client('cognito-idp', REGION)

user_records = client.list_users(UserPoolId=USER_POOL_ID)
print(user_records)
```