# How do I download a folder from AWS S3 with CloudPathLib from a public bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, data-science, boto3, pathlib

I'm trying to download a folder from a public AWS S3 bucket using the Python library `cloudpathlib`. My code looks like this:

```
from cloudpathlib import CloudPath
path = r"C:\some\path\to\folder"
url = "s3://some-example-bucket/folder/"

cloud_path = CloudPath(url)
cloud_path.download_to(path)
```

Really straight forward. To my knowledge, this should work, because the bucket is public:

[image]

Here is the bucket policy (nabbed from the AWS S3 tutorial):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cozy-auto-texture-sd-repo/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run the Python code to install the folder `stable-diffusion-v1-4` the following error message appears:

```
  File "E:\Cozy-Auto-Texture-Files\venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\auth.py", line 418, in add_auth
    raise NoCredentialsError()
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

My question is why is this happening? My bucket shouldn't require credentials since it's public. Is there something I'm missing with the buckets permissions or is it a Python code thing?

Thank you for reading and I appreciate the help!

Edit:

I've tried again with this method:

```
BUCKET_NAME = 'cozy-auto-texture-sd-repo'  # replace with your bucket name
KEY = 'stable-diffusion-v1-4'

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

try:
    s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY, sd_path)
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
        print("The object does not exist.")
    else:
        raise
```

However the same error message `botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials` appears, leading me to believe there is something wrong with my S3 bucket setup.

Comment: Is the local path the issue?

Comment: @Damienknight Possibly? I'm running this in a Venv so maybe there is something there that's the issue. Do you mean `path` or the path `cloudpathlib` was installed to?

Comment: I mean your 'path'.  Try taking the s3 path out of the equation using cloudpathlib.local for testing

Comment: @Damienknight I've tried again with another method (see the edit above) and I'm still getting the same error. There isn't anything wrong with the save path that I can see since its just going to an empty drive.

Comment: This is answered in the docs: https://cloudpathlib.drivendata.org/stable/authentication/#accessing-public-s3-buckets-without-credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that AWS S3 doesn't allow you to download a folder from a public bucket. I got around this by simply zipping the folder I was trying to distribute and unzipping it in my application when the download was complete.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running this script locally, you may need to first set up your AWS credentials on your local machine.

See this [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35802492/19840609):

> It worked with an `~/.aws/credentials` file containing:

> ```
> [default]
> aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
> aws_secret_access_key=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
> ```

> Using `aws configure` also works if you have `aws-cli` installed.

Answer (score 0):

if you have aws cli you could do something using subprocess.call.

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path(r"C:\some\path\to\folder")
import subprocess
url = CloudPath("s3://some-example-bucket/folder/")
subprocess.call(f"aws s3 sync {url.as_uri()} {path}", shell=True)
```

###### Note depending on what your preferences you may want call the command in a different way (`subprocess.check_output()` or `shell=False`, but command is split by `' '`)