# Why isn't boto3 (AWS) using ~/.aws/credentials?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

My issue is AWS boto3 package, authorization, python.

Referencing to https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html section: "Configuring credentials" the aws credentials for boto3 instance can be sought from  from
"4. Shared credential file (`~/.aws/credentials`)"

To proof the `~/.aws/credentials` are valid and sufficient I am using aws cli (`secretsmanager: create-secret, get-secret-value` calls). The response/results are OK.

Not so the boto3 instance in python code (using `client.get_secret_value`).

Expected: error free response

Actualy:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred
(UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the GetSecretValue
 operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

Any hint appreciated, thnx.

Comment: Make sure you are using an updated version of boto3. I've seen some shenanigans with versions older than 1.18.

Comment: using:
name = "boto3"
version = "1.26.28"

Comment: you have to pass profile if you are using other than default profile. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58431571/6285054 if you are running locally or some server.

Comment: Please add your `client` or `session` initialisation code to the question.

Comment: Debug print of the results of STS [get_caller_identity](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.get_caller_identity) will clarify the credentials actually being used.

Comment: Also consider enabling [boto debug logging](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/boto3.html) to see what's actually happening.

Comment: thank you for suggestions, in my case the problem was env values  used in IDE context, shadowing   the incoming default values from   .aws/credentials. Problem solved.

Comment: Did you use `boto3.Session` class to create a session and specify the credentials to use when creating the client, rather than relying on the shared credentials file?

Comment: Harry, great to hear you got it solved! Please add an Answer to help future readers. (Yes, you can answer your own Questions.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem's cause and solution: I forgot to check my IDE interpreter env setup which overrode the user's os env when code is executed by IDE.